# Getting items from a list of lists if the list contains any keywords?

Tags: python, list

In my Python code, there are two objects, (`x`, `y`).

`x` is a numpy array from a separate function containing an x, y, and z coordinate. Each x, y and z coordinate corresponds to an object in list 'y'.

and 'y' would be a list of letters between a - j in random order.

There are  be multiple instances of each letter i.e.: a b b c d a a f b d e e f e c a so on. For every value of 'x', there is a corresponding 'y' letter. Each line is different.

I want to get the `x` that corresponds a list of chosen letters, say a, c, and f.

How can I do this? I've tried looking into slices and indices but I'm not sure where to begin.

Trying to grab an item from array x, that corresponds to the same line in list y, if that makes any sense?

Comment: Just use sort on both lists, and match em up. Python sorts letters from least to greatest as well.

Comment: Would the 1 correspond to the a and the 3 correspond to the c?

Answer (score 4):

You wanted the values corresponding to 'a', 'c', and 'f':

```
>>> x = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
>>> y = 'cgadfh'
>>> d = dict(zip(y, x))
>>> d['a']
3
>>> [d[char] for char in 'acf']
[3, 1, 5]
```

'a' is the third character in y and 3 is the third number in x, so `d['a']` returns 3.

Incidentally, this approach works the same whether y is a string or a list:

```
>>> x = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
>>> y = ['c', 'g', 'a', 'd', 'f', 'h']
>>> d = dict(zip(y, x))
>>> [d[char] for char in 'acf']
[3, 1, 5]
```

Comment: Not really incidentally :)

Comment: The problem with this approach is, if the same character corresponds to more than one number, this will fail.

Comment: @thefourtheye In that case, it does behave differently than your solution but it does _not_ "fail".  Note the problem statement refers to wanting "the x" which is singular, not plural, with the clear implication that there will be only one integer corresponding to each of the random letters and that one integer is desired, not a list.  Since the problem statement does not contemplate multiple matches, it does not specify what behavior, if any, would be preferred.

Comment: Hi John! Thanks for the reply, but I made a mistake writing the question and yes, the letters do correspond to different numbers. I am trying to re-write the question now

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function to achieve this

```
X = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Y = ["a", "f", "c", "a", "c", "f"]

from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)
for idx, y in enumerate(Y):
    result[y].append(X[idx])
print result
```

**Output**

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [1, 4], 'c': [3, 5], 'f': [2, 6]})
```

Comment: +1 because, although it has a different interpretation of the question, this is also a nice approach.

Answer (score 0):

If X is just an indeces started from 1 then you can do the following:

```
exp = ['a', 'c', 'f']
output = [idx+1 for idx, ch in enumerate(Y) if ch in exp]
```

Otherwise you can try zip or izip or izip_longest:

```
import string
import random

a = range(15)
b = random.sample(string.lowercase, 15)
exp = random.sample(b, 3)

output = [k for k, v in zip(a, b) if v in exp]
```